# Is tarot reading considered haram if not taken seriously?

Tags: halal-haram

I paid to do a tarot card reading just for fun (my friend reccommended it). 
When I went the tarot card reader just put cards out and told me about my past, present, and future. 
Of course I don't believe in it, i'm not taking it seriously.

Is it haram what I did?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand you actually are aware that tarot reading is haram. And believing it is shirk.

Be aware that you've committed several mistakes (sins): You apparently went intentionally to a tarot reader and you've paid him knowing that his "profession" is haram.

So beside wasting your time in a bad (sinful) manner you even wasted your wealth for it and indirectly helped a sinful business.
While Allah the almighty tells us:

> ...  And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty. ([5:2](https://legacy.quran.com/5/2))

And our prophet () informed us further:

> He who visits a diviner ('Arraf<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup>) and asks him about anything, his prayers extending to forty nights will not be accepted. ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/173))

<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)'arraf عراف is a fortune-teller.</sup>

You should repent from what you've done sincerely and avoid repeating it. Even if you reject this internally what you've done was sinful and therefore haram. The only thing which might be considered as an excuse for you is your ignorance of the ruling, but repenting is the first and most necessary step you should start with.

For further information also refer to this fatwa islamqa #[32863](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/32863/he-went-to-a-fortuneteller-and-is-asking-whether-he-can-repent-and-how-he-may-repent) where they differ between 3 types of visiting a fortune-teller here a short summary:

1. Visiting a fortune-teller while not believing him is haram.
2. Visiting and believing him is disbelief.
3. Visiting and advising him to leave this haram business is halal.

Comment: Is the ruling about visiting a fortune teller the same regarding what your intention is? For instance a journalist visiting a fortune teller and pays him/her in order to grab information about how fortune tellers work, I.e exposing the scam and tricks that are used, and publishing it for educational purposes for instance?