# Is watching tarot and astrology videos haram? Even if I only do it because it's fun and it passes time?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-basis, religion

I am fully aware that it is haram, I only watch them because they're entertaining to watch and they pass time when I'm feeling stuffy or restless. They're kind of like asmr, but more soothing to me because of the shuffling of cards and the general talk of astrology and such knowledge. I view them like bed time stories and lores and stuff, I obviously don't take them seriously nor do I believe them, but they're hella entertaining. Is it haram nevertheless to watch them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/57887/37617

Answer (score -1):

I used to watch tarot readings, but then I stopped watching them as I realize that it is shirk. But I also have the same question that if I don't take them seriously and watch only for entertainment purpose then what's the problem with that? It's all about our believes. I don't believe in such readings but I like to watch them.
Like if we're going to visit a tomb of a sofi or saint, are we doing shirk? We are not praying and believing them.

Comment: This is a new question in the answer section. You may have noticed that a question duplicate was linked. If the given answer(s) don't answer your question, use the ask question link at the top of the page and ask a new question!